# Rambam's Letter to Samuel Ibn Tibbon on Translation

Tags: rambam

anyone know where I could find Rambam's letter to Ibn Tibbon on translation?  He talked about how not to translate too literally, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=8YMrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=rambam+ibn+tibbon&source=bl&ots=roxRX_bQoW&sig=w_c44ITVHiKMxszCl4-FUH1d-ME&hl=en&ei=swOQTZjjAY2htweg3rCICQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBzgK#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a free one from Google Books.If your willing to Pay  [Here](http://www.traditiononline.org/news/article.cfm?id=104966)  from Tradition Online.

Answer (score 1):

The Hebrew version is available in Kovetz Teshuvot HaRambam V'Igrotav [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43026&st=&pgnum=200&hilite=). The English translation by Leon Stitskin printed in *Tradition* 4:1 is available [here](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%204/No.%201/A%20Letter%20of%20Maimonides%20to.pdf).